# long and wide format equivalents in ggraph

Tags: r, ggraph

I am trying to make graph similar to this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggraph)
iris_g <- den_to_igraph(as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(iris[1:4]))))
xy_expand <- function(xy, expand) xy * (1 + expand / 10)
ord <- match(as.numeric(V(iris_g)$label), seq_len(nrow(iris)))  
V(iris_g)$Petal.Length <- iris$Petal.Length[ord]
V(iris_g)$Petal.Width  <- iris$Petal.Width[ord]
V(iris_g)$Sepal.Length <- iris$Sepal.Length[ord]
V(iris_g)$Sepal.Width  <- iris$Sepal.Width[ord]
V(iris_g)$Species      <- iris$Species[ord]

ggraph(iris_g, layout = "dendrogram", circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_diagonal() +
  geom_node_point(aes(filter = leaf,
                      x = xy_expand(x, Sepal.Length),
                      y = xy_expand(y, Sepal.Length)),
                  color = "red") +
  geom_node_point(aes(filter = leaf,
                      x = xy_expand(x, Sepal.Width),
                      y = xy_expand(y, Sepal.Width)),
                  color = "green") +
  geom_node_point(aes(filter = leaf,
                      x = xy_expand(x, Petal.Length),
                      y = xy_expand(y, Petal.Length)),
                  color = "blue") +
  geom_node_point(aes(filter = leaf,
                      x = xy_expand(x, Petal.Width),
                      y = xy_expand(y, Petal.Width)),
                  color = "yellow")
```

[image]
I would like to specify `aes(color = Trait)` so that the coloring integrates nicely into the rest of the figure but I cannot figure out if there is an equivalent to long data format in `ggraph`

The equivalent of what I want to do in `ggplot` would be:

```
library(ggplot2)
iris %>%
  mutate(id = seq_len(nrow(iris))) %>%
  gather(key = Trait, value = Value, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = Value, color = Trait)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Use `tidygraph`, keep both the edge and node data in long form, as part of the `tbl_graph` class, and then you can add the colour to the `geom_node_point`

Comment: Do you have some example code, the documentation for tidygraph is quite sparse and `iris_g %>%
  as_tbl_graph %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  gather(key = Trait, value = Value, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)` does not work.